# Loop from excel data into a dictionary with multiple values per key

Tags: python, excel, for-loop, dictionary, openpyxl

I am fairly new to Python and I think this question is fairly easy but I can't figure it out...

I have a data table in excel in which I have B column strings and C through I columns as values. I want to create a dictionary in which for each key value in
B column, I assign values of the columns C through I. I figured out how to do it per row, one at at time but I'm looking for a `for` loop syntax to do it
throughout the entire excel data table.

Here's my code:

```
NYSE = {}
NYSE.setdefault(sheet['B5'].value, []).append(sheet['C5'].value)
NYSE.setdefault(sheet['B5'].value, []).append(sheet['D5'].value)
NYSE.setdefault(sheet['B6'].value, []).append(sheet['C6'].value)
NYSE.setdefault(sheet['B6'].value, []).append(sheet['D6'].value)
print NYSE
```

I can keep manually adding to this...B7 C7, B7 D7, etc, but there must be a way to loop this in a function and output the dictionary.

Comment: Are you able to convert it to a csv file?

Comment: Yes i could use either csv or xlsx file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for line in open("pyex.csv").readlines():
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.split(",")
    key, value = line[0], line[1:]
    d[key] += value
print(d)
```

So if you have a csv file that looks like this. Where the first column are strings, and every column second and after are the values:

```
crow    19    13
bird    16    32
```

this code would output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'crow ': ['19', '13'], 'bird': ['16', '32']})
```

[Finished in 0.1s]

This allows you to have multiple values for each key, since the values are contained in a list.

**UPDATE:**

Using `setdefault` instead:

```
d = {}
for line in open("pyex.csv").readlines():
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.split(",")
    key = line[0]
    for value in line[1:]:
        d.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'crow': ['19', '13'], 'bird': ['16', '32']}
```

Or even with the csv library

```
import csv

csv_file = open("pyex.csv")
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

d = {}
for line in csv_reader:
    key = line[0]
    for value in line[1:]:
        d.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
print(d)
```

As @martineu said, you don't need defaultdicts or setdefaults:

```
import csv

csv_file = open("Book1.csv")
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

d = {}
for line in csv_reader:
    key = line[0]
    d[key] = line[1:]
print(d)
```

Comment: i tried this quickly but i got the following error: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {})

Comment: hmmmm, do you think it would be okay if I could see your csv file? I also edited my answer to accommodate more values.

Comment: I wil try using `setdefault` instead

Comment: How is that @Deuce525?

Comment: Hey i think that update with setdefault got me closer but it printed an empty dictionary {}

Comment: okay sorry it didn't help my csv was empty from the start, grabbed the wrong one....anyway i think its working!  its going through it now and seems to be working but its working through over 2,000 rows

Comment: You don't need to use `setdefault()` (or `defaultdict`s) for this. Just initialize the values for all the key strings from column B to an empty list first. Afterwards, you can safely append values from the other columns to each of them.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Pandas?  I'm not sure what your goal is with the data, but it seems like the most robust way to do what you want.

If you use `pandas.read_excel(path, sheetname=None)` then it will default to creating a dictionary where each key is a sheet and each value is a dataframe of that sheet.  You can then iterate over your dictionary to merge them all together.  It would be easier to get more specific with a pseudo-sample of your data.

Comment: does this allow to have each row in the data be assigned both key and mulitple values?  For example, B column are all keys and C, D, E are all values per row in the table.

Comment: I'm having a hard time visualizing your data.  Are these columns spread across multiple sheets that need to be related on a key, or are they just columns within the same sheet?  Either way the answer is yes - a dataframe is essentially a relational structure that lets you work with data by rows and columns and perform all sorts of operations.